# CMIS Versioning not working as expected

Tags: java, versioning, cmis

I'm creating a file on my document service with CMIS API using the following code:

```
zipMapFile.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "sap:versioned");
zipMapFile.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "g" + g.getId() + ".zip");
Document versionedDocument = openCmisSession.getRootFolder().createDocument(zipMapFile, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
newZipFileId = versionedDocument.checkOut();
...
```

The code above is working and the file is being correctly generated. When I run the following code:

```
cmisSession.getObject(newZipFileId.getId());
```

I get the file that I created before, with no errors.

However, I'm having a problem when I try to upload a new version for this file.

To do this, I'm using the following piece of code:

```
oldZipFileId = newZipFileId;
Document pwc = (Document) cmisSession.getObject(oldZipFileId);
pwc.setContentStream(contentStream, true);
newZipFileId = pwc.checkIn(false, null, null, null);
```

Whenever I do this, I can access the newer version with no problems running the following code:

```
cmisSession.getObject(newZipFileId.getId());
```

However, I can't access the older version anymore! If I try to run:

```
cmisSession.getObject(oldZipFileId);
```

I get an **CmisObjectNotFoundException**

The moment that I lose the access to the older version is exactly when the method `pwc.checkIn(false, null, null, null);` is executed. After this call, trying to get the object referenced by oldZipId gives me a CmisObjectNotFoundException.

I'm using MongoDB.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

And the working code should look like the following:

```
Document versionedDocument = openCmisSession.getRootFolder().createDocument(zipMapFile, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
oldZipFileId = versionedDocument.getId();

newZipFileId = versionedDocument.checkOut();
Document pwc = (Document) cmisSession.getObject(newZipFileId);
pwc.setContentStream(contentStream, true);
newZipFileId = pwc.checkIn(false, null, null, null);

// access last version
cmisSession.getObject(newZipFileId.getId());

// access old version
cmisSession.getObject(oldZipFileId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not an expert with versioning in the HCP Document Service everything you write works as designed AFAIK. When you checkIn a pwc there will be a new actual version (latest version in the history), and the pwc is gone. Consequently, your oldZipFileId identifying the pwc becomes invalid. The new actual version that the pwc became gets a new object id. This seems to be exactly what you observed.

Comment: so I can't access the old version anymore? I thought that using CMIS versioning I would have the possibility to access all versions of the document

Answer (score 0):

See if the old version is in [document.getAllVersions()](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Document.html#getAllVersions()).

Comment: No. When createDocument() method is executed, a version is created and getAllVersions() returns the version. In the next line, when pwc.checkOut() is executed, a new version is created and getAllVersions() returns two versions. However, when a real new version is created by calling pwc.checkIn(), getAllVersions() still returns only two versions. The first version, that was created by createDocument() is not lost (it still exists), however, the second version, created by checkout() method, is replaced by the new version created by the checkIn() method.

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear, if you couldn't understand please tell me

Comment: Are the two Documents returned by getAllVersions() correct after checkIn?  Inspect contentStream and properties on the objects returned by getAllVersions.   Previous references to Document objects might change after checkIn.  Also, I think it is okay for the PWC to disappear after successful checkIn.